# Visual Studio 2012/2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2012

Estou fazendo um Curso *Técnico de Informática*, e atualmente estou vendo e treinando programação, devido a isso instalei o ***Visual Studio(2012 e 2015)***, esses dias quando fui criar um projeto no ***Visual Studio*** que instalei percebi uma leve diferença entre ele e o que uso no curso!

Na do `Solution Explorer` o símbolo que aparece na frente do nome do projeto(por exemplo de um `form`) é um quadrado com um `VB` dentro:

> [image: VB,infelismente a imagem ta ruim]

,sendo que no do curso o que aparece dentro desse quadrado é o C#!

> [[image: c#]

quando instalei o ***2012***,logo no inicio eu selecionei a linguagem `C#`,mas aparece o `VB` e não o `C#`!

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carol,

No Visual Studio, quando vamos criar um novo projeto temos a opção de escolher entre as linguagem [C# (C Sharp)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp), [VB (Visual Basic)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) entre outras, então se atente na escolhar da linguagem na hora de criar seu projeto, uma simples escolhar errada pode alterar totalmente a forma de construir-lo.

Veja na imagem abaixo as linguagens disponível no visual studdio 2015.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que destaquei o Visual C#, esse é o projeto que você tem que escolher, ainda dentro da linguagem existem o tipo de projeto que pode variar entre [MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx), [Windows forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd30h2yb(v=vs.110).aspx), [Web forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx) entre outros.

Veja tudo isso antes de começa seu projeto.

Comment: Marconcilio,muito obrigada pela resposta,vou olhar no visual studio isso para não ter mais problemas!

Comment: @CarolM Esta resposta pode ser marcada como correta. É só você clicar no **✓** abaixo das setas para votar. Isso ajuda outros usuários que tiverem o mesmo problema que você a saberem que esta é uma forma de corrigir e também é uma forma de agradecer o autor da resposta *=)*.